# Delete or update user in Azure AD suddenly doesn't work for my application token

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm running an application for some weeks where I can CRUD users within an Azure Active Directory. For this purpose I have a registered application at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/application with Microsoft Graph application permission `User.ReadWrite.All`, which should be sufficient according to [the documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_delete). For the target Azure AD I got the [admin consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#using-the-admin-consent-endpoint). And everything worked as expected till today (just yesterday I used it to delete / change some users).

But today when I try to delete a user:

```
DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com:443/v1.0/users/cb4b831d-d199-46f6-b605-7f740db43f77
```

I'm getting a Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException:

```
Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
StatusCode: Forbidden
```

The JWT token I'm using is this:

```
{
  "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/3e6b8333-c708-4fa9-85d5-b38544125dc5/",
  "iat": 1536736865,
  "nbf": 1536736865,
  "exp": 1536740765,
  "aio": "42BgYCg959At7uqtzRE+cZPzsk52AA==",
  "app_displayname": "My Application",
  "appid": "5c02d1d6-a978-4139-a183-df9c40a5ea63",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/3e6b8333-c708-4fa9-85d5-b38544125dc5/",
  "oid": "461e08f0-4f2d-4965-81b2-6fa25bab4b9a",
  "roles": [
    "User.ReadWrite.All",
    ... // Some more roles
  ],
  "sub": "461e08f0-4f2d-4965-81b1-6fa25bab4b9a",
  "tid": "3e6b8333-c708-4fa9-85d5-b38544125dc5",
  "uti": "MjEZIJffRk61f--eTphYAA",
  "ver": "1.0"
}
```

If I'm going to delete a user by using the user token of an admin, it works as expected. So the request itself and parameters seem to be okay, just the token of the application doesn't work anymore.

So someone any idea or an explanation, why from today my application isn't able to delete / change users?

Comment: May be the token has expired? Related reference:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes

Comment: Nope. Now it is outdated, but I tested it a few seconds right after creation and according to `nbf` and `exp` it was valid for 65 minutes. Also it would return a different error message with the description "The token is expired".

Comment: Does this user (`cb4b831d-d199-46f6-b605-7f740db43f77`) have Admin priviledges in this tenant?

Comment: Nope. It's a normal user with no specific role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of a sudden, today everything works again as expected without any code change on my site.

Delete and change of a user just works as expected. This is very strange and I don't delete this question/answer, just to make everybody aware that sometimes the graph interface behaves awkward.